# TiApplication: (KrollRuntimeThread) [44,147] Sending event: exception on thread: KrollRuntimeThread msg:java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

**Environment:**

- `Titnium SDK:` 5.2.2.GA or 5.1.2.GA
- `Android API:` 23
- `Appcelerator Studio`    4.5.0.201602170821
- `Device:` OnePlus (Andriod OS: 6.0.1, Screen: 5.5) and Samsung Galaxy s6edge (Andriod OS: 6.0.1, Screen: 5.1)

**Description**

When I am running my app(a default project) to emulator (Genymotion or device), it's crashing on device and emulator.

**Error**

```
WARN] :   TiTempFileHelper: (main) [15,15] The external temp directory doesn't exist, skipping cleanup
[WARN] :   V8Object: (KrollRuntimeThread) [88,103] Runtime disposed, cannot set property 'userAgent'
[ERROR] :  linker: /data/app/com.ityug.gstanduppoker-2/lib/arm/libti.sq.so: has text relocations
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: (KrollRuntimeThread) [44,147] Sending event: exception on thread: KrollRuntimeThread msg:java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: /data/app/com.ityug.gstanduppoker-2/lib/arm/libti.sq.so: has text relocations; Titanium 5.2.2,2016/03/28 14:12,b685ddb
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: /data/app/com.ityug.gstanduppoker-2/lib/arm/libti.sq.so: has text relocations
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:372)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Runtime.loadExternalModules(V8Runtime.java:132)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Runtime.initRuntime(V8Runtime.java:99)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime.doInit(KrollRuntime.java:205)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime$KrollRuntimeThread.run(KrollRuntime.java:114)
```

Comment: Does it work on the emulators present in Android SDK folder? Also do you have any other android device to test with or is this specific. Does KitchenSink run on the device?

Comment: Experienced this myself, I think one of your modules is causing the problem. Are you running it on a marshmallow device?

Comment: Yes you are right, as I am running on Marshmallow device so one of the module (Ti.SQ) is not supporting there so it is causing the problem. When I removed it worked.